# Is there a way to shorten while loop code from user's input?

Tags: python, input, while-loop, split

```
def main():

  month = 0
  date = 0
  year = 0
  date = [month, date, year,]
  user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy: ")
  user = user.split('/')
  list1 = list(user)
  months = {'1': 'January', '2': 'Feburary', '3': 'March', '4': 'April', '5': 'May', '6': 'June',
          '7': 'July', '8': 'August', '9': 'September', '10': 'October', '11': 'November', '12': 'December'}

  while int(list1[0]) > 12  or int(list1[0]) < 1:
    print("Month is incorrect.")
    user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
    user = user.split('/')
    list1 = list(user)

  while int(list1[1]) > 31 or int(list1[1]) < 0:
    print("Date is incorrect.")
    user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
    user = user.split('/')
    list1 = list(user)

   while int(list1[2]) > 15 or int(list1[2]) < 15:
    print("Year is incorrect.")
    user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy:")
    user = user.split('/')
    list1 = list(user)

  print(months[list1[0]], list1[1], (",") , ("20") + list1[2])



main()
```

Is there a way to shorten the `while` loops into a single loop? I know there's something called "nesting", but that also seems to be long.

For the `user = user.split('/')` and `list1 =list(user)`, is there another way I can make a list from the user's input? I tried `user = user.split('/')`, but it seems there were some errors associated with it when I tried.

Comment: Note that there is a fundamental flaw in your algorithm - if the user gets e.g. the year wrong first time, then corrects the year but gets the month wrong, it won't be re-checked.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than writing it all out yourself, just farm it out to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            date = datetime.strptime(
                input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy: "),
                '%m/%d/%y',
            )
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input, please try again.')
        else:
            break
    print(date.strftime('%B %d, %Y'))
```

Python comes *"with batteries included"*; use them! In use:

```
>>> main()
Enter according to mm/dd/yy: 31/05/15
Invalid input, please try again.
Enter according to mm/dd/yy: 05/31/2015
Invalid input, please try again.
Enter according to mm/dd/yy: 05/31/15
May 31, 2015
```

---

In terms of simplifying your existing approach, I would suggest something like:

```
#  Define valid inputs
DAYS = set(range(1, 32))  # Note that not all months have all of these...
MONTHS = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', ...}
YEARS = set(range(2015, 2016))

def main():
    while True:
        date = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy: ")
        try:
            month, day, year = map(int, date.split("/"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not valid input.")  # not numbers, or didn't have two slashes
            continue
        if day not in DAYS:
            print("Not a valid date.")
            continue
        # Similar for months, years
        break
    print("{month} {day:02d}, 20{year:02d}".format(
        month=MONTHS[month],
        day=day,
        year=year,
    ))
```

However, this will accept e.g `"02/31/15"` as perfectly valid input, when it certainly isn't an acceptable date; using the specific date parsing functions in Python lets you avoid this issue without writing lots of your own checking code.

Answer (score 1):

```
months = {'1': 'January', '2': 'Feburary', '3': 'March', '4': 'April', '5': 'May', '6': 'June',
          '7': 'July', '8': 'August', '9': 'September', '10': 'October', '11': 'November', '12': 'December'}

def main():      
  while True:
    user = input("Enter according to mm/dd/yy: ")
    user = user.split('/')
    list1 = list(user)
    if not 1 <= int(list1[0]) <= 12:
        print("Month is incorrect.")
        continue
    if not 0 <= int(list1[1]) <= 31:
        print("Day is incorrect.")
        continue 
    if not 15 <= int(list1[2]) <= 15:
        print("Year is incorrect.")
        continue
    break

  print(months[list1[0]], list1[1], (",") , ("20") + list1[2])
```

#### Notes

1. In the new version, the `input` statement appears only once.
2. The original version of the code accepted a day of `0`.  I continued that in the revised code.
3. An equivalent form for the print statement that some may find easier to read is:

   ```
   print('{} {}, 20{}'.format(months[list1[0]], list1[1], list1[2]))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There a few issues in your code here, it seems you're more interested in a code review than anything else?

There a few semantic errors here:

What happens to a date like 30th of February? 02/30/2015

Suppose I enter these strings of values.

```
Enter according to mm/dd/yy:
>> 12/01/14
Year is incorrect.
>> 99/99/15
```

What would your program print out?